# Issue with global variables in python

Tags: python, selenium

I am getting issue with global variable declared in python file.
I do not have class declaration in the file.
i am just declaring some variables in the class with none type.
and modifying that variables in the function.

when i was calling those variables inside another class by importing them,
instead of modified value it is returning None type only.

Below is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from Pages.PageMethods.Google_Methods import Methods


browser = None
s = None


def before_feature(context, feature):
    print("before feature")

def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    print('before scenario', scenario.name)
    context.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    #context.driver.maximize_window()
    browser = context.driver
    global s
    s = Methods(browser)
    s.samplemethod()

def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    print("after scenario", scenario.name)
    context.driver.quit()

def after_feature(context, feature):
    print("after feature")
```

->Here i was calling that 's' variable inside another class,it is returning None type only instead of object for that assigned class

Please someone help

Here is the code that i am calling that variable

```
from features.environment import *


use_step_matcher("re")

fileConfig('logging.ini')
log = logging.getLogger('sLogger')


@given("i am on google page '(.*)'")
def navigate(context, url1):
    context.url = url1
    log.info("this is log statement")
    context.driver.get(url1)
    context.driver.implicitly_wait(10)


@then("I enter value into search box as '(.*)'")
def step_impl(context, text):
    print("selector:=>", Google.search_box)
    context.driver.find_element(*Google.search_box).send_keys(text)
    print("url in second step is:=>", context.url)
    time.sleep(1)
    s.printtitle()
```

and i was getting this error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'printtitle'

Comment: You should show how you are "calling that 's' variable inside another class".

Comment: Hi Daniel, i was importing the variables from that class as  "from features.environment import * "   and calling method in the "Methods" class as => s.print_title()

Comment: Where are you doing the import, inside or outside the class?

Comment: Could you post your calling code as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need use global operator

example:

```
global_var = list()

def somefunc():
    global global_var

    global_var.append(1)

somefunc()
print global_var
```

out:
[1]

Comment: hi maxim 

actually i have done that,with in the class that is working fine.but my issue is when i was using that variable in another class ,then it is returning that Nonetype to me instead of modified value in the function where i have assigned new value to it

Comment: Well, debug it with debugger. You need find place, where variable was changed. And you must be shure what happend when you import module, may be your variable not changed yet

Comment: i couldnt figure out the exact cause of the issue.while i was trying to print the global variables also ,it was giving None only